# Imitating the audio quality of a typical mobile phone video

Tags: mixing, techniques, commercials, sound-design

Hi All,

I've been tasked with sound design for a commercial (for Web), where the final mix should sound, in the client's words, 'like it was filmed with a mobile phone. I.e. lo-fi, but not too much. It should however, not at all sound like a TV commercial".

The cut I've been given have embedded (camera)audio that already sounds, well, bad. This is my source audio. So I don't think I will have to go far to get it sounding lo fi. I do however have to make a sound for a pop-up logo and text.

So:

- Which process(es) would you use to degrade the audio to that 'mobile phone' quality ?
- Would you mix the logo and text sfx to the same quality as the other elements or would you have it 'placed above' the rest of the mix(including foleys, raw audio etc) ?

My approach would be to do all the foleys and spot fx, with emphasis on the main actions (the character dive bombs into a pool, for instance), mix it down at high quality and then export to and then back from iMovie on my iPhone to get that nasty sound.
Then I'd do a second mix with the sound design elements on top and mix that down at high quality again.

Cheers,

Kurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use speakerphone by audioease.

http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html

"A bad GSM connection on a busy sidewalk, a bullhorn with feedback and a helicopter overhead, or a 1952 rockabilly guitar amp in a recording studio live room: The Speakerphone audio plug-in gives you authentic speakers of any size together with their natural environments.

All the walkie-talkies, distant transistor radios, upstairs TV sets, bullhorns, cell phones and guitar cabinets you will ever need. Speakerphone (Mac , Windows, iLok or challenge response) will add dial tones, operator, static, and you can select from a wealth of ambiences on either the caller or receiver's end.

400 speaker impulse responses, 23 microphones, 106 'Covers' (from blankets to car trunks), 53 Altiverb rooms and outdoor spaces, 5 gigabyte of ambiences and sound FX, and 12 DSP modules from Leslie to GSM compression, conveniently presented to you in well over 500 presets."

This plug-in is amazing.

Answer (score 4):

worldizing! play and record the whole thing through a cellphone and alter the original until it sounds halfway there. the clients will then likely want you to back off some more.